# Android application - long loading

Tags: android, garbage-collection, loading

I've developed this app, everything works fine, but loading takes 4-5 seconds and I don't know why, because there is no image or internet content to be loaded, just logcat spreads about 500 messages about garbage collector. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? here's some code:

```
 public class HNappActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements 
 HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener, CABNavLis{

  HeadlinesFragment hnHeadlinesFragment;
  int hnCatIndex = 0;
  int hnArtIndex = 0;
  Categories hnCurrentCat;
  public String[] Rubriky = null;
  int count;

  @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_hnapp);

      Rubriky = ((HNapp) this.getApplication()).getRubriky();
      count=((HNapp) this.getApplication()).getCount();

      hnHeadlinesFragment = (HeadlinesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
              R.id.headlines);
      hnHeadlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);

      hnCatIndex = savedInstanceState == null ? 0 : savedInstanceState.getInt("catIndex", 0);

      hnHeadlinesFragment.setSelectable(true);
      restoreSelection(savedInstanceState);
  }

  void restoreSelection(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         if (savedInstanceState != null) {
             setNewsCategory(savedInstanceState.getInt("catIndex", 0));
                 int artIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("artIndex", 0);
                 hnHeadlinesFragment.setSelection(artIndex);
                 OnHeadlineSelected(artIndex);
        }
    }
```

activity_hnapp.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">    
    <fragment
     android:id="@+id/headlines"
     android:name="sk.ecopress.hn.android.HeadlinesFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1.03" />
   <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/relative_layout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/titulka"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:padding="0dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:text="@string/titulka" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/sekcie"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/titulka"
       android:text="@string/sekcie"
       android:padding="0dp" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/bookmarks"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sekcie"
       android:text="@string/bookmarks"
       android:padding="0dp" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/info"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:padding="0dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:onClick="info"
       android:text="@string/info" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/nastavenia"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:padding="0dp"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info"
       android:onClick="settings"
       android:text="@string/nastavenia" />
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the garbage collection is working hard it's because you are creating a lot of garbage :). Run over in debug line by line and see which line gets stuck.
From the code you've posted it's non of the android sdk code that generate this garbage.
My bet would be on the line:

> Rubriky = ((HNapp) this.getApplication()).getRubriky();

What does it do? accessing a local file or something?

Comment: In addition to this, if the getRubriky method is doing some heavy loading, you should possibly move this call to a background thread instead of calling it on the UI thread, which by definition is the only thread running.

Comment: it is accessing local variable, variable that can be changed from all activities. it is just string array, maximum of 12 elements.

Comment: @MilošLukačka Go over step by step in debug and find the problem, we can't guess what's wrong until you dive in and get the exact line the causes the problem.

Comment: do you know about some cool tutorial how to work with debug things like stepping through lines?